# Naming Sql columns

Tags: mysql

Is there a problem in naming an SQL column with this setup _ -
So for example:

NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY

Because if I want to alter the type of this column from int to double then I get this error:

```
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NULL DEFAULT NULL at line 1**
```

Comment: Please include the command you issued to change the type. Also, why do you expecting a "naming problem" when you are merely changing the type of a column and not its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minus character is not allowed as unquoted identifier:

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

You can either escape your column name with a backtick or use an underscore instead of a minus char.